# processingで動くボールが跳ね返るようにしたい

Tags: processing

ボールを動かすコードはわかるのですが、跳ね返るようにする方法がわかりません。
お力添えをお願い致します。

以下ボールを動かすコードです。

```
float x;
int velocityX=1;

void setup(){
size(400,300);
x=0;
}

void draw(){
background(0);
x += velocityX;
fill(255,255,50);
ellipse(x,height/2,20,20);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

まず、私は日本語が話せないことを指摘したいと思います。これが私の最初の答えです。私はGoogle翻訳を使用したので、誤って誰かに知らせてしまった場合は謝罪してください:)

ボールが壁に当たったかどうか（左または右）を確認する必要があります。当たった場合は、速度を正（増加）から負（減少）に変更します。

コードでは、次の要素が必要です。
-[状態の場合](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=en&tl=ja&u=https%3A%2F%2Fprocessing.org%2Freference%2Fif.html)
-[または論理演算子](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=en&tl=ja&u=https%3A%2F%2Fprocessing.org%2Freference%2F)
-[乗算演算子](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=en&tl=ja&u=https%3A%2F%2Fprocessing.org%2Freference%2F)

上記の単語を疑似コードに翻訳する：

ボールのx位置が右壁（スケッチ幅）より大きいか、ボールのx位置が左壁（0）より小さい場合、速度は符号を反転する必要があります（正から負、逆も同様）。

擬似コードをコードに変換する：

```
//ボールのx位置が右壁または左壁より大きい場合（0）
if(x > width || x < 0){
   //方向を反転（速度）（+1 * -1 = -1、-1 * -1 = +1）
  velocityX = velocityX * -1;
}



velocityX = velocityX * -1;
```

より簡潔に書くことができます

```
velocityX *= -1;
```

上記をコードに追加します。

```
float x;
int velocityX=1;

void setup() {
  size(400, 300);
  x=0;
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  x += velocityX;

  if (x > width || x < 0) {
    velocityX *= -1;
  }

  fill(255, 255, 50);
  ellipse(x, height/2, 20, 20);
}
```

閉会の挨拶：

-私はコードを整然とフォーマットしておくことをお勧めします（Ctrl + T / CMD + T）：読みやすく、平均してコードを書くよりも読むのに多くの時間を費やします。
-必ず処理チュートリアルを確認してください：[バウンド](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=en&tl=ja&u=https%3A%2F%2Fprocessing.org%2Fexamples%2Fbounce.html)、[バウンドボール](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=en&tl=ja&u=https%3A%2F%2Fprocessing.org%2Fexamples%2Fbouncingball.html)
-[Daniel Shiffmanのyoutubeビデオ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIKRXl3wH8Y)をご覧ください。英語ですが、クローズドキャプション（CC）>自動翻訳>日本語オプションが役立つことを願っています。翻訳は完璧ではありませんが、うまくいけば視覚的な説明が理にかなっています。